# Text position on TabHost

Tags: android, text, position, android-tabhost

I created activity with tabhost: Code below:

```
<TabHost
                    android:id="@+id/tabhost1_zabytek"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <TabWidget
                            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/tlo12"

                            />
                    <FrameLayout

                            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            >
                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </TabHost>
```

And programically try set text position:

```
TabHost host= (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost1_zabytek);
final View view = host.getTabWidget().getChildTabAt(0);
final textView = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

So , when I run my application on device with android 4.1 all is ok.

[image]

But, when I run my application on device with android 2.3, application display text on tabhost in a wrong position.

[image]

My application should display text position Gravity.Center on each version Android. What should I do?? How solve  my problem?